# Node-js : Sending many attachments with Node Cisco Spark Client

Tags: node.js, cisco

I use Node Cisco Spark Client (https://github.com/marchfederico/node-sparkclient) for sending message with any attachments.
I can send 1 attachment, but not many.

This is my code :
Can you help me please ?

```
function postMessage(roomId,message,nbfichiers) {
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){

     var messageParams = {}
     var sanitizedMessage = '>'+message.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")

    if (nbfichiers.length > 0){
        console.log("Nombres de pièces jointes : " + nbfichiers.length);
        for(var b=0; b < nbfichiers.length; b++){
            messageParams.file = fs.readFileSync('uploads/'+nbfichiers[b]+'');
            messageParams.filename = nbfichiers[b];
            messageParams.markdown = true

            sparkClient.createMessage(roomId,sanitizedMessage,messageParams,function(err,message){
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                else {
                    fulfill(message)
                }
          });

                fs.unlinkSync('uploads/'+nbfichiers[b]);

        }
    }
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a loop inside a `new Promise(...)` you will only get the result of the first iteration when you consume the promise, is it really the behaviour that you are expecting ?

According to the [node-sparkclient documentation](https://github.com/marchfederico/node-sparkclient) you can only send one attachment at a time. You could send multiple attachments by using `Promise.all` the following way :

```
function postAttachment(roomId, message, file) {
    return new Promise(function (fullfill, reject){

        var messageParams = {}
        var sanitizedMessage = '>'+message.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
        messageParams.file = fs.readFileSync('uploads/'+file);
        messageParams.filename = file;
        messageParams.markdown = true  

        sparkClient.createMessage(roomId, sanitizedMessage, messageParams, function(err,message){
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                fs.unlinkSync('uploads/'+ file);
                fullfill(message)
            }
        });
   })
}

function postAttachments(roomId, message, files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(file => postAttachment(roomId, message, file));
}
```

If you want to send only one attachment with all the files, you could merge your files before sending them.